# Converting an object of an array

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsdecimalnumber

I have the following block of codes in my program.

```
  for(int k=0;k<reqroom.count;k++)
  {
   NSString *rent=[roomRent objectAtIndex:k];

   NSString *tax=[roomTax objectAtIndex:k];

   NSString *no=[textvaluearray objectAtIndex:k];

   NSDecimalNumber *rentd=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:rent];
  }
```

//here roomRent,roomTax and textvaluearray are NSMutableArrays

This is the error that I am receiving:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b2ce0'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception "-[__NSArrayI length]:" it looks like "rent" object is not a string type and its array. Can you check the type of "rent" before converting to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

What is `reqroom`? Is it an `NSString` or `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`)? If it's some sort of array and you want to iterate as many times as there are objects in the array, you should probably do something like

`for(int k=0;k<[reqroom count];k++)`